# SQL number of first names belonging to two families

Tags: sql, grouping

Say I have a table with three columns : the first column is the id, the second contains first names and the third column contains last names. They can be rows with the same name but different last names. However, the same name cannot occur twice with the same last name twice in the table.

| ID | First_Name | Last_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | SMITH |
| 1 | John | BROWN |
| 2 | John | JONES |
| 3 | John | WILLIAMS |
| 4 | John | MILLER |
| 5 | John | DAVIS |
| 6 | John | WILSON |
| 7 | John | TAYLOR |
| 8 | John | WHITE |
| 9 | John | CLARK |
| 10 | Michael | SMITH |
| 11 | Michael | BROWN |
| 12 | James | JONES |
| 13 | James | WILLIAMS |
| 14 | Robert | MILLER |
| 15 | Robert | DAVIS |
| 16 | Robert | WILSON |
| 17 | Robert | BROWN |
| 18 | Robert | JONES |
| 19 | Robert | WILLIAMS |
| 20 | Jennifer | MILLER |
| 21 | Jennifer | DAVIS |
| 22 | Jennifer | SMITH |
| 23 | Jennifer | BROWN |
| 24 | Jennifer | JONES |
| 25 | Jennifer | WILLIAMS |
| 26 | Jennifer | WILSON |
| 27 | Jennifer | TAYLOR |
| 28 | Jennifer | WHITE |

How do I get a matrix **M** whose rows and columns are all possible values of last names and M(f1,f2) represents the number of first names who occur with f1 and f2 in the table?

i.e to get this result

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: If your data is in CSV files, then SQL is not really appropriate.  If the data is in a database, please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I just edited the question I hope it is clearer now. For the database I cannot upload it sorry

Comment: Maybe a sample of the expected output would help clarify. Also re: @GordonLinoff comment, you don't need to upload the database, just tag your question with which Database you are using i.e. sql-server, SQLLite etc.

Comment: I just added an example of the output

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Getting a (dynamic) matrix as a result of a pure SQL is not doable.
The best you can do is to get the 2 last names in 2 columns, like this:

```
SELECT
   t1.last_n name_a, t2.last_n name_b,
   count(case when t1.first_n = t2.first_n then 1 end) count_match   
FROM data_table t1,data_table t2
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

The results would look like this (this is like the expected results just not in a matrix):

```
Results
    name_a  name_b      count_match
    BROWN   BROWN       4
    BROWN   CLARK       1
    BROWN   DAVIS       3
    BROWN   JONES       3
    BROWN   MILLER      3
    BROWN   SMITH       3
    BROWN   TAYLOR      2
    BROWN   WHITE       2
    BROWN   WILLIAMS    3
    BROWN   WILSON      3
    CLARK   BROWN       1
    CLARK   CLARK       1
    CLARK   DAVIS       1
    CLARK   JONES       1
    CLARK   MILLER      1
    CLARK   SMITH       1
    CLARK   TAYLOR      1
    CLARK   WHITE       1
    CLARK   WILLIAMS    1
    CLARK   WILSON      1
    DAVIS   BROWN       3
    DAVIS   CLARK       1
    DAVIS   DAVIS       3
    DAVIS   JONES       3
    DAVIS   MILLER      3
    DAVIS   SMITH       2
    DAVIS   TAYLOR      2
    DAVIS   WHITE       2
    DAVIS   WILLIAMS    3
    DAVIS   WILSON      3
    JONES   BROWN       3
    JONES   CLARK       1
    JONES   DAVIS       3
    ....
```